# Qual o significado dos dois pontos nessa linha?

Tags: c++

A linha é:

```
foo() : myValue1(0xDEADBEEF), myValue2(0xBABABABA) {}
```

Não consigo entender o que ela faz.

Aqui o código completo:

```
class foo{
public:
foo() : myValue1(0xDEADBEEF), myValue2(0xBABABABA) {}
    int myValue1;
    static int myStaticValue;
    virtual void bar() {printf("call foo::bar()\n");}
    int myValue2;
}
```

Comment: Olá. Güstavo! Esse é o stackoverflow em português. Por favor, traduza a sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esses dois pontos indicam uma lista de inicialização, isto é, uma lista de chamada de construtores de membros de dados da classe. Para membros de dados primitivos (por exemplo, "int myField" no seu código) na prática o efeito é o mesmo de uma atribuição.

Veja no exemplo abaixo duas declarações do contrutor "foo" que são equivalentes.

```
class foo {

  public:

    // #1
    // foo() : myValue1(0xDEADBEEF), myValue2(0xBABABABA) {}

    // #2
    foo() {
      myValue1 = 0xDEADBEEF;
      myValue2 = 0xBABABABA;
    }

    int myValue1;
    static int myStaticValue;
    virtual void bar() {printf("call foo::bar()\n");}
    int myValue2;
}
```

Quando os membros de dados são instâncias de outra classe, no entanto, o uso da lista de inicialização é a única maneira de inicializar esses membros.

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
class A
{
  public:
  A(int x, int y)
  {
    // faz alguma coisa com x e y
  }
}

class B
{
  public:

  B(int i, int j) : a(i, j)
  {
    // ...
  }

  A a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta linha:

```
foo() : myValue1(0xDEADBEEF), myValue2(0xBABABABA) {}
```

Significa que os valores `myValue1` e `myValue2` estão sendo iniciados com os valores `0xDEADBEEF` e `0xBABABABA`, respectivamente. Este construtor é chamado de ***Member Initialization***.

Só para entender melhor, o código acima é similar (não igual) ao construtor do tipo ***Member Assignment***, que no mesmo exemplo seria:

```
foo()
{
   myValue1 = 0xDEADBEEF;
   myValue2 = 0xBABABABA;
}
```